# Adding xmllite.lib to Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c++, xml, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, xmllite

I'm trying to compile an Intel Appup sample program 'SlideshowexampleApplication', which requires Xmllite.lib.  I searched and see that I'm supposed to add this file to the linker options in Visual Studio 2008, but I don't see the linker option under Project properties->Configuration properties. I tried adding 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Include' as an Additional Include Directory, but I'm still getting a compile error.

> Build started: Project: PicasaExampleComponent, Configuration: Debug Win32
> Creating library...
>
> LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'XMLLite\lib\XmlLite.lib'

Here is the example project:
http://appdeveloper.intel.com/en-us/article/slideshow-example-windows

Comment: Which directory is the lib in?

Comment: It's in C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Lib which I've added in the Additional Include Directories list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the sample app is using a relative path for the library file, prepending XMLLite\Lib to the library filename.

<strike>This could be happening as a result of a `#pragma` in the sample app code, can you run `findstr` on the source code to see if there are any references to `XmlLite.lib`?</strike>

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7f0aews7(v=VS.100).aspx for info on #pragma as it is used in this way.

EDIT:
Actually the projects in this sample are set up to reference an XmlLite that is installed with the sample code:

> G:\SlideshowExample>findstr /si
>   xmllite.lib *.*
>   PicasaExampleComponent\PicasaExampleComponent.vcproj:
>   AdditionalDependencies="XMLLite\lib\XmlLite.lib"
>   PicasaExampleComponent\PicasaExampleComponent.vcproj:
>   AdditionalDependencies="XMLLite\lib\XmlLite.lib"
>   PicasaExampleComponent\PicasaExampleComponent.vcxproj:
>   XMLLite\lib\XmlLite.lib;%(AdditionalDependencies)
>   PicasaExampleComponent\PicasaExampleComponent.vcxproj:
>   XMLLite\lib\XmlLite.lib;%(AdditionalDependencies)

You can either use that one or get the one you have installed with the SDK properly included.

Comment: Thanks, I copied the files into the XmlLite directories and it compiled.